# Kendo UI: AutoComplete closing right after opening

Tags: javascript, typescript, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement the kendo autocomplete with my a custom API.
The API returns about 1800 items and has a search time of a minute or longer, that's why I'm trying to load only 50 at once and reload everytime the content of the input changes.

My code is the following:

```
  public async GetProductsWithSample(options: DataSourceTransportOptions, searchString) {
      AjaxCall(ajaxData, true).then(products => {
            options.success(products.data);
            console.log(products.data);
        });
    }

  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: (options: DataSourceTransportOptions) => {
                    let searchString = $("#product-chooser").val();
                    GetProductsWithSample(options, searchString);
                }
            }
        });
        const refresh = (dataSource, autoComplete) => {
            dataSource.read().then(() => {
            });
        };
        const autoComplete = $("#product-chooser").kendoAutoComplete({
            filtering: (e) => {
                refresh(dataSource, autoComplete);
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            change: (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();  
            },
            placeholder: 'Product',
            dataTextField: "name",
            dataSource: dataSource
        }).data("kendoAutoComplete");

        $("#product-chooser").on("focusin", (e) => {
            const value = $("#product-chooser").val().toString();
            autoComplete.search(value);
        });
```

And now my problem:

When I focus in or type something, the values update but close after less than a second.
However, this only happens within the first ~30 seconds of loading the page. After the page had been loaded for a bit, it works completely fine, there is no consistency behind it, sometimes it works first try. That is why I'm suspecting it is a kendo bug.
However, I might also be making a crucial mistake. Can someone tell me if they spot a mistake?

Thanks in advance!